# render image field current path into an image in django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-models

In the django image field, embedded in a form, the term "currently" is displayed along with the path to the image that is currently associated with the model field.

How do I render the actual image, instead of the "currently" and path info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just create an html image and reference the path in the src attribute.